# Basic question on the infinitely many solutions of a linear system Ax=b,

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations, intuition, plane-geometry

I just want to verify the geometry of solutions to $Ax=b$, for the case when we have infinitely many solutions:

If say for a $3\times 3$ matrix, after Gaussian Elimination, I have two pivot variables and one free variable - for simplicity, assume the free variable is the third coordinate $x_3$.

Then the infinitely many solutions form a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Is there a similar geometric intuition for when I have only one pivot variable, and *two* free variables?  Do the infinitely many solutions form a *plane* in $\mathbb{R}^3$?  I am pretty sure it does, but just wanted to ask the question, in case I am mistaken.  The solutions would be in the form of linear combinations of two linearly independent vectors, so I think these two vectors will span a *plane*.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have one pivot variable, your reduced (augmented) matrix is of the form

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}a&b&c&d\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$$

then the solution is of the form $ax+by+cz = d$, which is the equation of a plane.

Comment: Simple and awesome explanation, @Snow.  Thanks so much :-)

Comment: No problem. Glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if $n$ is the nullity of the matrix corresponding to a homogeneous linear system, then the solution space is a $n$-dimensional subspace (it passes through the origin). If we have a corresponding consistent non-homogeneous system, the solution space is the affine space obtained from the aforementioned subspace by a translation through any particular solution.

Comment: Thanks @A.P., I see that you were careful to mention the *affine space* of solutions.  So the space need not be a vector space?  Perhaps due to the fact that the plane / n-dimensional space does not pass through the origin?  Thanks,

Comment: In practice problems, I have only ever seen solution spaces that are vector spaces, I believe, from linear algebra to ODE, so I just want to confirm what you are conveying.  Thanks so much,

Comment: @user301446 The only time the solution space will be a vector space is when the system is homogeneous; otherwise, it will be affine, i.e., a translated vector space. For instance, look at Snow's example: there the solution space is a plane $ax + by + cz = d$. This plane isn't a vector space unless $d = 0$, i.e., unless the system is homogeneous. Similarly, solutions to *homogeneous* linear ODEs form vector spaces, and the corresponding solutions for nonhomogeneous linear ODEs are translates of the homogeneous solutions by a particular solution.

Answer (score 0):

A way to think about this is, we let $x=x_p+x_h$, so that $x_p$ is the particular solution and $x_h$ is the homogeneous solution.

We can fix $x_p$ and for any other solution $x$ to the equation, $x_h=x-x_p$ is in the nullspace of $A$.

$Ax=b, Ax_p=b\Rightarrow A(x-x_p)=b-b=0\Rightarrow Ax_h=0$

Since the nullspace is a vector space, adding $x_p$ back to it is "shifting" it to the correct location.

Hence all solution sets are "shifted" vector spaces or the empty set, in case of no solution.